# How do I Edit an item from a table list

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core

I have a Controller that returns a list of estate

```
     public async Task<IActionResult> Estate()
        {
            ViewBag.PageName = "Estate";
            if (await _estateRepository.Count() > 4)
            {
                var estateList = await _estateRepository.GetAll();
                var firstEstates = estateList.Take(4);
                foreach (var estate in firstEstates)
                {
                     await _estateRepository.GetCountOfCustomersOfAnEstate(estate.EstateId);

                }
                ViewBag.fiveEstates = firstEstates;
                ViewBag.Estates = estateList;
            }
            var estates= await _estateRepository.GetAll();
            ViewBag.Estates = estates;
            return View();
        }
```

and a view that renders these list

```
 <table id="datatables" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover dataTables-example">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>SN</th>
                                <th>Name</th>
                                <th>Adress</th>
                                <th>Email</th>
                                <th>Phone</th>
                                <th>Total residents</th>
                                <th>Code</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            @foreach (var estate in ViewBag.Estates)
                            {

                                <tr class="gradeX">
                                    <td>
                                        @(rowIndex++)
                                    </td>
                                    <td>@estate.EstateName</td>
                                    <td>
                                        @estate.Address
                                    </td>
                                    <td>@estate.Email</td>
                                    <td class="center">@estate.PhoneNo</td>
                                    <td class="center">@estate.NoOfCustomers</td>
                                    <td class="center">@estate.EstateCode</td>
                                    <td class="center" title="Edit"><a id="@estate.EstateId"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a></td>
                                    <td class="center" title="Delete"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></td>
                                </tr>
                            }
                        </tbody>

                        <tfoot>
                            <tr>
                                <th>SN</th>
                                <th>Name</th>
                                <th>Adress</th>
                                <th>Email</th>
                                <th>Phone</th>
                                <th>Total residents</th>
                                <th>Code</th>
                            </tr>
                        </tfoot>
                    </table>
```

what i want to achieve is to pop up a modal with that particular information for edit. when the edit button is clicked on any row. 
this i think could be done by passing the id of the item to the controller which will retrieve the estate that matches the `ID` passed and send back to the scripts which will then initiate the modal.

please help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MVC 5 Edit Bootstrap Modal Popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30078978/mvc-5-edit-bootstrap-modal-popup)

Comment: Yes it did thanks Rahul