# Edit item modal popup asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I try to use this example: [MVC 5 Edit Bootstrap Modal Popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30078978/mvc-5-edit-bootstrap-modal-popup)
I have `Index` page, on which I send `onclickEdit(id)` I have `Edit` page, where my modal html is placed.

.js:

```
{     
var id = $(elem).data('assigned-id');     
alert("1");     
$.ajax({         
url: '/Course/Edit/id=' + id,         
success: function (data) {             
alert("2");             
$('#modalWrapper').html(data);             
$('#editModal').modal();         
}     
}); 
}
```

alert("1") works, alert("2") not.

controller:

```
public IActionResult Edit(Guid id)         
{             
return PartialView(_courses.Find(id));         
}
```

I checked, I come into `Edit()`, it passed, but I don't come into ajax success
What shoud I change?
Many thanks

Comment: Please show full javascript for the `onclickEdit` function, instead of just the `success` handler. If the `success` handler isn't being called then that isn't where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing string input `'show'` in the `modal()` function. By adding it, it will make the modal visible.

`$('#editModal').modal('show');`

Bootstrap documentation:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/modal/#modalshow

#### Update

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/Course/Edit/id=' + id,
        type: 'GET',
        cache: false,
        success: function (result) {
            alert("2");
            $('#modalWrapper').html(result);             
            $('#editModal').modal('show');  
        }
    });
```

#### Update

Do you get any errors in the development console in the Chrome browser? Push F12 to access it.

[image]

Comment: It is the answer to the question: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/modal/#modalshow

Comment: Maybe say something about what OP did wrong or missed, and what's the solution of it and based on what, instead of just say "try this, try that"?

Comment: I said, that I never come into ```success: function (data) {```, because   ```alert("success");``` doesn't show. May be something wrong in my 
```public IActionResult Edit(int id)
        {
            return PartialView(products.Find(id));
        }
```
?

Comment: @Toto6ka can you show us more code? It would be great to see the entire ajax call. And the controller action method code as well thanks.

Comment: @Toto6ka Please add the code in your question and not in the comment. Its very difficult to read the code in the comments. Thanks.

Comment: I changed my question and added .js and controoler code

Comment: @Toto6ka I have updated my answer. Please check it out.

Comment: @Toto6ka Are you entering the `Edit` method in the controller?

Comment: I checked your update - doesn't work.
Yes, I entering ```Edit()``` method.

Comment: I have added a new update to my answer. Please have a look. You also need to return the name of the partial view like this `return PartialView("yourpartialviewname", _courses.Find(id));`